# Connect to Elasticsearch with a .p12 certificate and a password

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, ssl, certificate

I want to connect to an Elasticsearch server with Nodejs. As a prerequisite I have received a .p12 certificate and a password but I do not know how to new a client object with this credentials. In the [node.js official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/client-connecting.html) .pem files are used and there is no password. How can I achieve this with nodejs Elasticsearch library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found to options:

1. converting a .p12 to a .pem file [see the details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144046/converting-pkcs12-certificate-into-pem-using-openssl)
2. reading a .p12 file with password [see the details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42753566/nodejs-load-pfx-certificate-from-file)